# Can I allow users to disable Twitter Bootstrap Responsivness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a site built with twitter bootstrap 3. Everything works great and looks good on mobile/tablet as well. What I would like to do is add a link in the footer to allow user to view full site and not the mobile responsive version if they would like.

I know I can change viewpot to force the full site in mobile but I would like to have it default to responsive and should the user choose to want full site they click a link which would disable to responsive features.

I looked around and surprisingly haven't seen much documentation for this which I would think would be pretty popular as most sites have this functionality these days.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably have to serve two different versions of Bootstrap, one default and one with a modified `variables.less`

Have a look at this part of the file:

```
// Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed
@grid-float-breakpoint:     @screen-sm-min;
// Point at which the navbar begins collapsing
@grid-float-breakpoint-max: (@grid-float-breakpoint - 1);
```

You could change it to something like this to never show the mobile menu

```
// Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed
@grid-float-breakpoint:     0%;
// Point at which the navbar begins collapsing
@grid-float-breakpoint-max: 0%;
```

Call the compiled CSS file maybe `bootstrap-desktop.css` and then serve this CSS file instead of default if the user visits the desktop site

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to toggle the viewport meta tag.

By default have the tag in place.

When they choose desktop mode, add something to the URL or set a cookie to not output the meta tag.